# ZSH "command" expansion?

Tags: zsh, expansion

Simple question: Does zsh does have something like a `command expansion`?

Want I want to write in the command line is something like this:

```
git push [gitlab,origin] localBranch:remoteBranch
```

Since git does not support pushing to multiple remotes at once, I looking for a way that zsh expands the above to two individual commands, running:

```
git push gitlab localBranch:remoteBranch
```

and

```
git push origin localBranch:remoteBranch
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the short forms of the `for` loop.

```
for remote (gitlab origin) git push $remote localBranch:remoteBranch
```